# $A \subset B \implies f^{-1}(A) \subset f^{-1}(B)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

> **Prove:**
>
> $A \subset B \implies f^{-1}(A) \subset f^{-1}(B)$

I am busy setting up a proof for Real Analysis, and have come to a point where I need to use the above statement. Intuitively, I can draw a sketch of the above statement that quite clearly shows it to be true, but I would rather like to see an actual proof in order to know for certain that it is correct.

Can anyone please assist me in doing so?

Comment: Let $x\in f^{-1}(A)$; then $f(x)\in A$; therefore $f(x)\in B$. Hence $x\in f^{-1}(B)$.

Comment: This should be an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you have
$$
x\in f^{-1}(A)
$$
you can say $f(x)\in A$ and conversely. Thus
$$
x\in f^{-1}(A)\implies
f(x)\in A\implies
f(x)\in B\implies
x\in f^{-1}(B)
$$

Comment: Thank you! :). Since you posted first, I will accept your answer once the site allows me to :)

Comment: I do not want to mess your nice answer, but I think you meant "you can say $f(x)\in A$" not $x\in A$, because $x \in f^{-1}(A)$. I can't correct it myself, since it is only 3 characters.

Comment: @quapka Typo, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

Take an arbitrary $x \in f^{-1}(A)$. By definition, $f(x) \in A$. As $A \subset B$, $f(x) \in B$. As $f(x) \in B$, it must also lie in ....